# Where can I edit the default video metadata that is store for an iMovie project?

Tags: macos, youtube, metadata, imovie

### Problem:

I upload a series of videos to youtube and therefore I have created a Project in iMovie 10 (macOS). When I share to YouTube I define metadata like title, description, tags, etc. which are then displayed on the published video.

Export to YouTube view:
[image: Export to YouTube view]

But after adding many videos I always see the metadata that was defined for the very first video (title, description, tags, etc.) instead of the last one which was not the default behaviour of earlier versions of iMovie.

---

### Question:

Is there a way to change this to always prefill or load the last exported video metadata? Or is there any way to edit these prefilled metadata locally in any prefs file or similar? This would really be a time saver.